# VBA macro with formula showing (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a code in my macro that return me in my **Cell(A5)** result like `#name`?

```
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(20, 5)))"
End Sub
```

**`#name?`** include a formula of text between quotation marks in my VB code

```
=Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(20, 5)))
```

If i will write without quotation marks it will returns me a **result**.(sum of range)

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(20, 5)))
```

but I need to have in my cell **A5** result and formula, how i got this result.
Maybe it's enough to change some options?

Comment: Do you want to get in your cell both formula and result? If so, check answer below, http://stackoverflow.com/a/41298568/2707864

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to use a VBA code to enter a formula in Cell A5, then you need to use the right parameters:

`Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(20, 5))` is VBA, if you want it as a formula that an Excel sheet's cell recognizes, you need to use `R1C5:R20C5`.

Also, instead of `Application.Sum` just use `Sum`.

You should try avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell` and directly use `Range("A5").FormulaR1C1`

So just use the line code below:

```
Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(R1C5:R20C5)"
```

Comment: @Michael Shtefanitsa  have you tried my code in my answer ? if helped mark as "answer"

Answer (score 2):

I found it simpler to add a formula to the cell using

```
 Sub addFormula()

  Dim ws As Worksheet 
  Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Range("A5").NumberFormat = "General" 'This formats A5 as general
        .Range("A5").Formula = "=SUM(F1:F20)"
    End With

 End Sub
```

All it does is enters the formula into the cell A5

Comment: i try it too,  but it returns me  "=SUM('F1':'F20')"

Comment: i'm guessing that the cell is formatted as text...

By adding `.Range("A5").NumberFormat = "General"` i resolved this

Comment: @MichaelShtefanitsa - Are you sure you did what was suggested, or did you use `Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(F1:F20)"` - using `FormulaR1C1` would have misunderstood what `F1` and `F20` referred to and would have put `'` around them.

Comment: If the cell was formatted as text, the OP's current code would not be generating `#NAME?`, so the problem is almost certainly that they used `.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(F1:F20)"` rather than `.Formula = "=SUM(F1:F20)"`.

Comment: Yes i see exactly that. I'm sure that it isn't necessary to put `R1C1`. @MichaelShtefanitsa did you use `R1C1` for a specific reason?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have a formula in your cell pointing to some range you define in your VBA code, then you can use

```
Range("A5").FormulaR1C1 = "=Sum(" & Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(20, 5)).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ")"
```

Comment: its a different way, but nice to keep the `Cells...`

Comment: @ShaiRado, well it's actually a _different_ way in that all other solutions assume a _fixex_ range of `F1:F20` to be input in the cell formula, while mine assumes the OP can use same statement in different context and leave the range definition to VBA code. Let's see what Michael Shtefanitsa will say it actually needs...

Comment: I like the thinking "outside the box", but also `"=Sum(R1C5:R20C5)"` can be used with parameters `"=Sum(R" & firstrow & "C" & Col & ":R" & LastRow & "C" & Col &")"`

Comment: @ShaiRado, yes, it can. but it hasn't been... I just wanted to explore and add that path and sticking to OP's code

Comment: we are not disagreeing, i like your solution

Comment: @ShaiRado, I wasn't disagreeing either!

Comment: @MichaelShtefanitsa, did you get through it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to show in `A5` **both the formula and the result**.
If so, use

```
Dim aux As Variant
aux = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(20, 5)))
ActiveCell.Value = "Application.Sum(Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(20, 5))) : " & CStr(aux)
```

This code caould likely be improved (using `Sum` instead of `Application.Sum`, e.g.)